# Creating multiwallets

Tags: wallet-development

I want to create wallets for users. bitcoin core allow us to 
create one wallet. is there any way to create wallets for single bitcoin-qt which can able to run multi wallets at a time.I know I can rename my wallet and by re running bitcoin-qt it creates new wallet but it not allows to run both. 
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Research HD Wallets,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Bitcoin Core 0.16.0 introduced a multiwallet feature which is currently for the RPC interface only (the GUI part will come with the next major release). To have multiple wallets, start Bitcoin Core with the `-wallet=<wallet name>` option or add `wallet=<wallet name>` to your bitcoin.conf file. You must specify this option for each wallet you want to load.

For example, if you want to have two wallets named `wallet1` and `wallet2`, you would start Bitcoin Core as:

```
bitcoin-qt -wallet=wallet1 -wallet=wallet2
```

or add the following to your bitcoin.conf file

```
wallet=wallet1
wallet=wallet2
```